# How to protect/encrypt data stored in session/local storage in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am creating Blazor WebAssembly App and trying to figure how can i Encrypt/Protect data stored in Session Storage/ Local Storage ?

Comment: Why would you do that? The .NET assemblies are being downloaded to the client, so the code that decrypts (as well as the key) can easily be decompiled anyway...

Comment: Well i get your point but isn't making it harder  a better than leaving it plain text ?

Comment: Better for what? What are you trying to do/stop people from doing? People that are technical enough to read data from the local storage, most likely can also decompile a .NET assembly...

Comment: it like saying because thieves can break the locks, it is better to leave doors open no need to put locks.

Comment: No, it's like saying "_[Security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) is not a good strategy_" and it's not worth your time and effort (IMO). If the information must be secured, it should be stored on the server-side instead

Comment: Come on folks! He can make use of some obfuscate tools in order to protect the code from being decompiled. So, I think it worth while having some way do encrypt the data, right ? Well friend, take a look at this post:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-web-storage And here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280390/can-local-storage-ever-be-considered-secure You can find some solutions. Hope it helps. Let me know if is enough.

Comment: @HenkHolterman In my reading about MS's protectedlocalstorage, you must do that on the server side. It seeems to rely on building your app using the blazor server app template.

Comment: Yes, it is server-side. I didn't realize that then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things that you need to know is that **blazor wasm  model till .net 5 does not support crypto library**. (as my knowledge)

in .net 6 you can use [Blazor.SubtleCrypto](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blazor.SubtleCrypto/#readme-body-tab)

but you can inject AES method into it with javascript interop, follow these steps:

1. download [AES.js](https://github.com/ricmoo/aes-js)
2. add aes.js to wwwroot folder
3. add two following method in script tag in index.html root for encrypt/decrypt string

```js
    function encryptedText(inputSrt, keyArray) {
    var textBytes = aesjs.utils.utf8.toBytes(inputSrt);
    var aesCtr = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(keyArray, new aesjs.Counter(5));
    var encryptedBytes = aesCtr.encrypt(textBytes);
    return aesjs.utils.hex.fromBytes(encryptedBytes);
}

    function decryptText(inputStr, keyArray) {
        var encryptedBytes = aesjs.utils.hex.toBytes(inputStr);
        var aesCtr = new aesjs.ModeOfOperation.ctr(keyArray, new aesjs.Counter(5));
        var decryptedBytes = aesCtr.decrypt(encryptedBytes);
        return aesjs.utils.utf8.fromBytes(decryptedBytes);
    }
```

now your are ready. add DI interface to .NetCore follow these steps:

1. create class and interface

```cs
public interface IEncryptProvider
    {
        string TextEncrypt(string input);
        string TextDecrypt(string input);

        string Encrypt<T>(T input);
        T Decrypt<T>(string input);
    }
public class AesJsProvider : IEncryptProvider
    {
        IJSRuntime GetJSRuntime;
        public static int[] HiddenKey = new int[] { 0, 45, 6, 3, 8, 5, 8, 7, 89, 7, 10, 21, 12, 34, 12, 1 };
        public static string JsEncryptMethod { get; set; } = "encryptText";
        public static string JsDecryptMethod { get; set; } = "decryptText";

        public AesJsProvider(IJSRuntime jSRuntime)
        {
            GetJSRuntime = jSRuntime;
        }

        public async Task<string> TextDecrypt(string input)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                return string.Empty;
            try
            {
                return await GetJSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>(JsEncryptMethod, input, HiddenKey);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        public async Task<string> TextEncrypt(string input)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                return string.Empty;
            try
            {
                return await GetJSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>(JsDecryptMethod, input, HiddenKey);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        public async Task<string> Encrypt<T>(T input)
        {
            var str = JsonSerializer.Serialize(input);
            if (input == null)
                return string.Empty;
            try
            {
                return await GetJSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>(JsEncryptMethod, input, HiddenKey);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        public async Task<T> Decrypt<T>(string input)
        {
            var str = await TextDecrypt(input);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                return default(T);
            try
            {
                return await GetJSRuntime.InvokeAsync<T>(JsDecryptMethod, input, HiddenKey);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return default;

            }
        }
    }
```

so all of codes completed, lets config startup options

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IEncryptProvider, JSRuntimeProvider>();
```

you can change change **HiddenKey** as your need to a secret key in provider, and inject **IEncryptProvider** on any page to encrypt/decrypt string or objects

source code available in github:
https://github.com/mahdiit/blazor-wasm-encryptstorage