# Settings inside secrets.json did not load in ASP.NET Core Blazor webassembly

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 , Visual Studio 16.7.3 .

I have an API Key that needs to be used in my `blazor wasm` app. However I don't want to place the value in `appsettings.json` to make sure the `API Key` doesn't get into my source control. One such way to achieve is to use `secrets.json` in `ASP.NET Core`. But the value from `secrets.json` is not loading in my `Program.cs`.

**`appsettings.json:`**

```json
{
  "APIKey": "appsettings.json"
}
```

**`Program.cs:`**

```cs
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

Debug.WriteLine($"APIKey:{builder.Configuration["APIKey"]}"); // works appsettings.json is logged in output window
```

If I move the key from `appsettings.json` to `secrets.json`

**`secrets.json:`**

```json
{
  "APIKey": "secrets.json"
}
```

then output window log is empty. **`secrets.json`** no longer works in `blazor wasm`?

Comment: The problem is that anything that runs in the browser is visible to users. Blazor WASM runs in the client. Even if you use "secret" semantics, at some point that becomes exposed in your code. In all the docs they say never use secrets in client-side blazor.

Comment: you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62701224/1204153

Comment: but what about license keys. For example, If I'm using any 3rd party licensed UI components and that needs to be registered in program.cs with license key like `builder.Services.Add3rdPartyUIComponents("License Key")`. And how to keep this key as secret?

Comment: Someone had that exact same question: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23620

Comment: I tried to solve this the best i could do was request it from the server and it pulled that info from secrets. The connection is only https at that stage... However the keys where all removed from my source code.

Comment: @BrianParker Please can you explain more on what you have done?

Comment: @fingers10 Essentially I load the equivalent of appsettings from  and API endpoint. Convert that to a ```MemoryConfigurationSource ``` .   var clientConfigurations = await builder.LoadConfigFromServerAsync("api/clientconfigurations");
            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => clientConfigurations);